# Ionic RC0: error TS4053: Return type of public method from exported class has or is using name 'Entry' from external module

Tags: typescript, ionic2

I am upgrading my project to Ionic RC0 from Beta 11 by creating a new RC0 project and following the instructions in https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

I have sorted out most of the issues, except for couple. One among them is following errors:

```
error TS4053: Return type of public method from exported class has or is using name 'Entry' from external module "/Users/saiy2k/projects/ionic/gr/node_modules/ionic-native/dist/es5/plugins/file" but cannot be named

error TS4053: Return type of public method from exported class has or is using name 'FileError' from external module "/Users/saiy2k/projects/ionic/gr/node_modules/ionic-native/dist/es5/plugins/file" but cannot be named.

error TS4053: Return type of public method from exported class has or is using name 'DirectoryEntry' from external module "/Users/saiy2k/projects/ionic/gr/node_modules/ionic-native/dist/es5/plugins/file" but cannot be named.
```

I Installed the File cordova plugin, but still.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
    import {Entry} from 'ionic-native/dist/es5/plugins/file';
    import {FileError} from 'ionic-native/dist/es5/plugins/file';
    import {DirectoryEntry} from 'ionic-native/dist/es5/plugins/file';
```

Reference: [Typescript errors when setting declaration to TRUE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35193072/typescript-errors-when-setting-declaration-to-true)